# Hey, what time is it?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, date

### Challenge

Given a `number width`, `number height`, `hours` and `minutes` print the time using the following format style:

```
------  -  ------  ------  -    -  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------
|    |  |       |       |  |    |  |       |            |  |    |  |    |
|    |  |  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------       |  ------  ------
|    |  |  |            |       |       |  |    |       |  |    |       |
|    |  |  |            |       |       |  |    |       |  |    |       |
------  -  ------  ------       -  ------  ------       -  ------  ------
```

For numbers with a mid line, when the height is odd just place it in the middle (example for `height = 3`):

```
------
|    |
------
|    |
------
```

However, when the height is even you can choose up or down:

```
------  ------
|    |  |    |
|    |  ------
------  |    |
|    |  |    |
------  ------
```

Of course, you need to specify this and use it every time.

---

### Input

- **W**: The width of each number
- **H**: The height of each number
- **HRS**: Time hours
- **MINS**: Time minutes

---

### Output

You can either print the time, return a string (including the newlines) or return a list of strings (one string per line).

---

### Rules

1. Assume number width `> 2`
2. Assume number height `> 2`
3. The space between numbers is fixed to `2`
4. The space between hours and minutes is fixed to `4`
5. If hours or minutes are `< 10` (single digit), make sure to add a `0` (see example)
6. Assume that input hours and minutes will always be valid time
7. Digit `1` is a special case which always has the same width `1` and only it's height changes.
8. Height is considered the inner height, excluding the upper and lower rows of `---` (see example)

---

### Example

Here's an example for `W=6`, `H=4`, `hrs=2`, `mins=18`:

```
------  ------    -  ------
|    |       |    |  |    |
|    |  ------    |  ------
|    |  |         |  |    |
|    |  |         |  |    |
------  ------    -  ------
```

Comment: Are we allowed to return the result as a list of strings / list of character lists?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Check the edit. Should be clear now.

Comment: @Arnauld Totally, missed to mention this. Yes, `1` always has a width of `1` and only it's height changes. I will edit.

Comment: @Arnauld Yes it is.

Comment: @Arnauld Should add this as a rule? I thought it's visible on the example.

Comment: It probably should. That's a bit disturbing, since **H** and **W** are not defined the same way.

Comment: @DimChtz Generally, you shouldn't even need test-cases to be able to make a valid answer, they're really only for making sure answers work

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>258</s> <s>245</s> <s>242</s> 239 bytes

```javascript
(w,h,H,M)=>[2,h-1,2,h,2].map((r,y)=>`${(g=x=>((k=[876,,1284,260,8461,276,788,8484,780,268][x%10|0])?(s=x=>' -|'[[21,8,5,10,4,2][k*2>>y*3&7]>>x&3])().padEnd(w-2,s(4))+s(2):'-|||-'[y])+'  ')(H/10)+g(H)}  ${g(M/10)+g(M)}
`.repeat(r/2)).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7daoNAFITv@xRepNlz4tG4G6tLwe1VwRufYFlQojF/VdHQKDHPbjfQm4H5hhnmXPwWw74/dTevactqOSQL3OlIKWWYKC3o6HGySsL4P0UH0NNkg3z1gDoZEwVwSbSMIyIuZEgiCkiGka1YFEtpjaWxDGwijR7feTAHBr9geJWZ481Ma8FJ0gfxgOyA0ZeNUGra7NaxUWpc7wwC@l1Rfjcl3D1BA4SI7gACP5k3z7PH9GTQZY7DENItD9CtIcWn46weNWT/IMPnW@73VVcVN@i3AtE/t6cmz5d92wzttfKvbQ0HiF4niEvE5Q8)

#### Character encoding

Digits are made of 3 distinct characters:

- 0: space
- 1: `-`
- 2: `|`

#### Pattern encoding

Each digit is made of 5 patterns:

```
0:  -----  <-- top pattern
1:  |   |  <-- upper side repeated pattern
2:  -----  <-- middle pattern
3:      |  <-- lower side repeated pattern
4:  -----  <-- bottom pattern
```

Each pattern is made of a leading character \$L\$, followed by a repeated middle character \$R\$, followed by a trailing character \$T\$.

All digits can be built by using only 6 distinct patterns, which are encoded as:

$$L+R\times16+T\times4$$

```
 ID | Leading | Repeated | Trailing | Codes | Encoded as
----+---------+----------+----------+-------+------------
  0 |   "-"   |   "-"    |   "-"    | 1,1,1 |    21
  1 |   " "   |   " "    |   "|"    | 0,0,2 |     8
  2 |   "-"   |   " "    |   "-"    | 1,0,1 |     5
  3 |   "|"   |   " "    |   "|"    | 2,0,2 |    10
  4 |   " "   |   " "    |   "-"    | 0,0,1 |     4
  5 |   "|"   |   " "    |   " "    | 2,0,0 |     2
```

#### Digit encoding

Because of its non-standard width, \$1\$ is a special case and is processed separately.

All other digits are encoded as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{4}2^{3n}P_n$$

where \$P_n\$ is the \$n\$-th pattern for this digit (0-indexed, from top to bottom).

```
 Digit | Patterns  | Encoded as
-------+-----------+------------ 
   0   | 0,3,3,3,0 |     876
   1   |    n/a    |     n/a
   2   | 0,1,0,5,0 |    1284
   3   | 0,1,0,1,0 |     260
   4   | 2,3,0,1,4 |    8461
   5   | 0,5,0,1,0 |     276
   6   | 0,5,0,3,0 |     788
   7   | 0,1,1,1,4 |    8484
   8   | 0,3,0,3,0 |     780
   9   | 0,3,0,1,0 |     268
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>296</s> <s>270</s> <s>256</s> <s>249</s> <s>244</s> 241 bytes

```python
w,h,H,M=input()
a,d,e='| -'
b,c=d*(w-2),e*w
f,g=e+b+e,d+b+e
l,r,m=a+b+d,d+b+a,a+b+a
E=eval
for L in['ceccfccccc']+~-h/2*['marrmllrmm']+['macccccrcc']+h/2*['malrrrmrmr']+['ceccgccgcc']:print E(L[H/10]),d+E(L[H%10]),d+d,E(L[M/10]),d+E(L[M%10])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7bCoMwDIbv@xS9GfUQccoYY9BLwQt9AvGia@sBWpXiJoOxV3dt2WBJCPnzf4Qsz3WYp3zfNxighJqO03JfgxAxECApeeGEoBtwKqJgS/IQZLShDnoq41ssQbiOFBjQlNlZ@A0DNzNUUPlgCnWzwRUep4ZwyXnHXZA2fidDmkcN0cwYrZTR2i6d9IDxzI9QxjI2PeGu9L5Ie13MOK24CKqmTLNjG9oHvDh8hQAn63@v9t6@n@EEOWSXDw)

Comment: I find it interesting how we're converging towards the same size, while implementing quite different methods in 2 different languages. :p

Comment: @Arnauld Yeah, I noticed that. Also that you edged ahead ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>101</s> <s>98</s> 96 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
┘｛ｌ２∔0×；＋｛ø；┤“\⤢ＹJ>`Ｓ‰/„２┬７ｎ＠｛⁴Ｙ？ｙ５＜？⁸»├⁸⇵|＊-∔ｙ３＜？↕；┐１；｝１ｙ２％‽⁷＋╷｝┘╋］⁷-×１ｙ５－⁸╵×⇵╵╋╋｝｝｝｝  ×＋｝ ４××＋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=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_,i=NSUwQTYlMEElNUIyJTJDMTglNUQ_,v=6)

Nothing too fancy - stores the 7 bytes of info of each number and draws according to them.
While making this I fixed 3 bugs in Canvas (though only one resulted in shortening the answer; [this](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTEwJXVGRjM4JXVGRjVCJXVGRjRDJXVGRjEyJXUyMjE0MCVENyV1RkYxQiV1RkYwQiV1RkY1QiVGOCV1RkYxQiV1MjUyNCV1MjAxQyU1QyV1MjkyMiV1RkYzOUolM0UlNjAldUZGMzMldTIwMzAvJXUyMDFFJXVGRjEyJXUyNTJDJXVGRjE3JXVGRjRFJXVGRjIwJXVGRjVCJXUyMDc0JXVGRjM5JXVGRjFGJXVGRjU5JXVGRjE1JXVGRjFDJXVGRjFGJXUyMDc4JUJCJXUyNTFDJXUyMDc4JXUyMUY1JTdDJXVGRjBBLSV1MjIxNCV1RkY1OSV1RkYxMyV1RkYxQyV1RkYxRiV1MjE5NSV1RkYxQiV1MjUxMCV1RkYxMSV1RkYxQiV1RkY1RCV1RkYxMSV1RkY1OSV1RkYxMiV1RkYwNSV1MjAzRCV1RkY1OCV1RkYwQiV1MjU3NyV1RkY1RCV1MjUxOCV1MjU0QiV1RkYzRCV1RkY1OC0lRDcldUZGMTEldUZGNTkldUZGMTUldUZGMEQldTIwNzgldTI1NzUlRDcldUZGMTIlRjcldTI1NzUldUZGNTUldTI1NEIldUZGNUQldUZGNUQldUZGNUQldUZGNUQlMjAlMjAldUZGMUIldUZGMEIldUZGMEIldUZGNUQlMjAldUZGMTQlRDcldUZGMUIldUZGMEIldUZGMEI_,i=NCUwQTYlMEElNUIyJTJDMTglNUQ_,v=6) is how the result would've looked without [that commit](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/commit/15a58edff82013c87cf50eb60fa8d0c6ae92e85d#diff-7a9076d6d94e62c13d641aa71f19ae8eL1051))

Explanation:

```
┘{                   for each item of the 3rd input
  l2∔0×;+              prepend 2-length 0s to the item
  {                    for each character
    ø;                   push an empty canvas below the character
    ┤                    cast the character to a digit
    “...„２┬７n            the number 741859858201224148989 base-2 decoded & split into chunks of 7 - the digit data
    @                    pick the item in that list corresponding to the current number
    {                    for each bit there
      ⁴Y                 store the index in the loop in Y
      ?                  if the current bit is set:
        ｙ5<?               if y < 5 (aka one of the vertical parts)
          ⁸»├                push height>>1 + 2 (y position of the part)
          ⁸⇵|*               push a list of ceil(height/2) "|"s
          -∔                 prepend a "-" to that
          y3<?               if y < 3 (aka the top parts)
            ↕                  reverse that list
            ;┐１;               replace the y position with 1
          }                  
          1                  push 1 (x position of the part)
          y2%‽               if y%2 is 0
            ⁷+╷                add the width to that, then decrement
          }                  
          ┘╋                 at those coordinates enter that array in the canvas pushed earlier
        ]                  else (aka y >= 5, the horizontal parts)
          ⁷-×                repeat "-" width times
          1                  push 1
          y5-⁸╵×⇵╵           push ceil((y-5) * (height+1) / 2) + 1
          ╋╋                 at (1; above line) in the canvas, place the dashes, without smart overlapping
        }            
      }              
    }                
  }                  
    ×＋                 join the 2 digits with 2 spaces
}                    
  4××＋               join the 2 numbers with 4 spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 101 bytes

```
ＮθＮη⊞υ¶Ｆ-|Ｆ⟦ι◧ιθ⁺◨ι⊖θι×ιθ⟧⊞υ⁺κ¶ＦＥ⪫Ｅ²◧ＩＮ²:⭆§⪪”)⧴9;ïjÞ⊟Pj%Uδ>LτS·Ｑr^ψＱ”⁵﹪℅ι¹⁶×÷§⟦²⊖η²η⟧μ²§υＩλ«Ｐι§⪪ι¶⁰→→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHRTsMgFH1ev4LwRBOWrJVSM5@Me5mxujjf5h5qy1YipV0Li4n67fWC29wiCTfnXLicew9FlXdFk6thmOvWmkdbv4mO7MKb4JxXwBe2r4ilCL9qDHTTdIjg8RcOkYcrSdEiLx/ExhCAuxCosj2B3LPcVj45E0UnaqGNKEECbkjYL7IW/W/JOkRHFV/7flA7ymV5S@4bqT2I//Tu8t6Q837d27ELeIohLk0n9dYV3Zq5LsUHWbZKGoJZmqYsSpIkYpwlDAJnVynjMRDOIKSQ40BTh@CATdzCFCXwbNaUVjXkqSulzhVxw0Q8PI0012Ym97IUJ9VVfOlB5dqkqFpTVPuOKTpeBQv8VCr0C30Go8wqI1uYBLwER0YLDy8nkgfHKJo410ZZsxdk6j/gP/0eBh6wIA6i62G8Vz8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the height and width.

```
⊞υ¶
```

Push a newline to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｆ-|
```

Loop over the characters `-` and `|`.

```
Ｆ⟦ι◧ιθ⁺◨ι⊖θι×ιθ⟧
```

Loop over the four values given by the character, the character padded to the width, the character on both sides of the width, and the character repeated across the width.

```
⊞υ⁺κ¶
```

Push those values plus a newline to the list. This results in the following elements for a width of 6:

```
-
     -
-    -
------
|
     |
|    |
||||||
```

(Note that the last one is unused, and the first and fifth elements are only one character wide.)

```
ＦＥ⪫Ｅ²◧ＩＮ²:
```

Input two numbers, convert to string, left pad to a width of 2, join them with `:`, then loop over the characters in that string.

```
⭆§⪪”)⧴9;ïjÞ⊟Pj%Uδ>LτS·Ｑr^ψＱ”⁵﹪℅ι¹⁶
```

Split the compressed literal `4777415551464544646437462454644547446662474744746400000` into blocks of 5, then take the block indexed by the code point of the current character modulo 16, thus mapping space to 0 and `:` to 10. Map over those characters.

```
×÷§⟦²⊖η²η⟧μ²§υＩλ
```

Look up the character in the predefined list, then multiply it according to its index; the first, middle and last strings get multiplied by `2/2` while the intermediate strings get multiplied according to the height.

```
«Ｐι§⪪ι¶⁰→→
```

Print the string without moving the cursor, then print the first line of the string again, then move the cursor a further two squares to the right. This means that `1` is special-cased because its first line is only a `-` while `:` is special-cased to have no intrinsic with at all and merely ends up doubling the space between digits.